what is the most efficient way to gather all points at a certain height?
I have a List[List[int]] that represents points [x,y]
points = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3]]

What is the most efficient way to gather-up all the points with a specific height ?
So if we want all points with a height of 3 ( y == 3 ) :
answer = [[1,3],[2,3]]

I'm assuming there is a more efficient way than this :
answer = []
for p in points:
    if p[1] == 3:
        answer.append(p)

Further, how to query the set of distinct heights that have at least one point ?
answer = [1,2,3]


I think you can use filter or list comprehension, as described in this question: How to return a subset of a list that matches a condition
answer = [p for p in points if p[1] == 3]


And to query the set of distinct heights that have at least one point, you could use Python's Set and iterate through the list, adding all heights. Sets don't allow duplicate values, so you'll get only distinct values.
heightSet = {p[1] for p in points}

If you want the result as list, just call list method.
distinctHeightsList = list(heightSet)


If you will only do this operation once, then indeed you can't do better than iterate on all points and test whether y==3 for each point.
In python this can be done using a list comprehension:
points = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3]]
points_at_height3 = [(x,y) for (x,y) in points if y == 3]

With library numpy the syntax is even more convenient:
import numpy as np

points = np.array(points)

points_at_height3 = points[points[:,1] == 3]

However, if this is an operation that you're going to repeat a lot, then you can preprocess the data first into a data structure that makes this operation faster.
For instance, you can group the points by height into a dictionary:
points = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3]]

by_height = {}
for (x,y) in points:
   by_height.setdefault(y, []).append((x,y))

print(by_height)
# {2: [(1, 2)], 3: [(1, 3), (2, 3)], 1: [(2, 1)]}

print(by_height[3])
# [(1, 3), (2, 3)]

Or alternatively you can sort the points by height, then use binary search to find the height you want:
from operator import itemgetter
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

y_coordinate = itemgetter(1)

sorted_points = sorted(points, key=y_coordinate)

def get_points_at_specific_height(sorted_points, y):
    i = bisect_left(sorted_points, y, key=y_coordinate)
    j = bisect_right(sorted_points, y, key=y_coordinate)
    return sorted_points[i:j]

print(sorted_points)
# [[2, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]

print(get_points_at_specific_height(sorted_points,3))
# [[1, 3], [2, 3]]

